# Android Collections.sort - doesn't work properly

Tags: java, android, sorting, collections

I'm trying to use the following code to sort an ArrayList of object based on date in desc order:

```
    List<GalleryBean> gallery_beans = this.galleryAdapter.getGalleryImageList();
    Collections.sort(gallery_beans, new Comparator<GalleryBean>() {
        public int compare(GalleryBean bean1, GalleryBean bean2) {
            final int BEFORE = -1;
            final int EQUAL = 0;
            final int AFTER = 1;

            /*
            if(bean1.getMediaDate() > bean2.getMediaDate()){
                Log.i("Collections.sort---->", "move bean1 name, long, date ---> ," + 
                        bean1.getMediaName() + ", " + bean1.getMediaDate() + ", " + new Date(bean1.getMediaDate()) + 
                        ", AFTER bean2 name, long, date ---> "+ bean2.getMediaName() + ", " + bean2.getMediaDate()  + ", " + new Date(bean2.getMediaDate()));
                return AFTER;
            } else if(bean1.getMediaDate() < bean2.getMediaDate()){
                Log.i("Collections.sort---->", "move bean1 name, long, date ---> ," + 
                        bean1.getMediaName() + ", " + bean1.getMediaDate() + ", " + new Date(bean1.getMediaDate()) + 
                        ", BEFORE bean2 name, long, date ---> "+ bean2.getMediaName() + ", " + bean2.getMediaDate()  + ", " + new Date(bean2.getMediaDate()));
                return BEFORE;
            } else {
                return EQUAL;
            }
            */
            return (int) (bean1.getMediaDate() - bean2.getMediaDate());
        }
    });

    for (Iterator<GalleryBean> it = gallery_beans.iterator(); it.hasNext(); i++) {
        GalleryBean gallery_bean = it.next();
        Log.i("ITERATOR---->", "gallery_bean name ---> " + gallery_bean.getMediaName() + " gallery_bean long date ---> " + gallery_bean.getMediaDate() + " gallery_bean date ---> " + new Date(gallery_bean.getMediaDate()*1000));
    }
```

From my research the commented out code should work but seems to do nothing.  The remaining line does some sorting but it isn't correct either.  Here is a snippet of the log output from the return (int) * code below.  I'm trying to sort based on date in long unix format.  Any help is much appreciated.

Regards,
JT_Dylan

```
11-24 21:03:47.407: I/ITERATOR---->(3949): gallery_bean name ---> IMG_20140815_140338.jpg gallery_bean long date ---> 1408125820000 gallery_bean date ---> Sat Sep 24 08:06:40 EST 46591
11-24 21:03:47.407: I/ITERATOR---->(3949): gallery_bean name ---> IMG_20140815_140408.jpg gallery_bean long date ---> 1408125850000 gallery_bean date ---> Sat Sep 24 16:26:40 EST 46591
11-24 21:03:47.407: I/ITERATOR---->(3949): gallery_bean name ---> IMG_20140815_152133.jpg gallery_bean long date ---> 1408130495000 gallery_bean date ---> Thu Nov 17 11:43:20 EDT 46591
11-24 21:03:47.407: I/ITERATOR---->(3949): gallery_bean name ---> IMG_20140815_152134.jpg gallery_bean long date ---> 1408130496000 gallery_bean date ---> Thu Nov 17 12:00:00 EDT 46591
11-24 21:03:47.407: I/ITERATOR---->(3949): gallery_bean name ---> IMG_20140815_152137.jpg gallery_bean long date ---> 1408130498000 gallery_bean date ---> Thu Nov 17 12:33:20 EDT 46591
11-24 21:03:47.409: I/ITERATOR---->(3949): gallery_bean name ---> IMG_20140815_152140.jpg gallery_bean long date ---> 1408130501000 gallery_bean date ---> Thu Nov 17 13:23:20 EDT 46591
11-24 21:03:47.409: I/ITERATOR---->(3949): gallery_bean name ---> IMG_20140815_152231.jpg gallery_bean long date ---> 1408130553000 gallery_bean date ---> Fri Nov 18 03:50:00 EDT 46591
11-24 21:03:47.409: I/ITERATOR---->(3949): gallery_bean name ---> IMG_20140815_153950.jpg gallery_bean long date ---> 1408131592000 gallery_bean date ---> Wed Nov 30 04:26:40 EDT 46591
11-24 21:03:47.411: I/ITERATOR---->(3949): gallery_bean name ---> IMG_20140815_154004.jpg gallery_bean long date ---> 1408131605000 gallery_bean date ---> Wed Nov 30 08:03:20 EDT 46591
11-24 21:03:47.411: I/ITERATOR---->(3949): gallery_bean name ---> IMG_20140815_154011.jpg gallery_bean long date ---> 1408131613000 gallery_bean date ---> Wed Nov 30 10:16:40 EDT 46591
11-24 21:03:47.411: I/ITERATOR---->(3949): gallery_bean name ---> IMG_20140815_154011_1.jpg gallery_bean long date ---> 1408131613000 gallery_bean date ---> Wed Nov 30 10:16:40 EDT 46591
11-24 21:03:47.414: I/ITERATOR---->(3949): gallery_bean name ---> IMG_20140815_162439.jpg gallery_bean long date ---> 1408134281000 gallery_bean date ---> Sat Dec 31 07:23:20 EDT 46591
11-24 21:03:47.414: I/ITERATOR---->(3949): gallery_bean name ---> IMG_20140815_162446.jpg gallery_bean long date ---> 1408134288000 gallery_bean date ---> Sat Dec 31 09:20:00 EDT 46591
```

Comment: i can't see which dates are in the wrong order. also, are you sure you want to multiply the media date by 1000 when creating the new Date object, because the year is 46591

Comment: Yes, the 1000 is for milliseconds which I receive from the server so I * 1000 for the local files to match.

Comment: If I do this: System.out.println(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()*1000));  I get a year of 46869, so I think the times are already in milliseconds. Your log above shows the year as 46591.

Comment: You are correct.  I removed the *1000 but the sort is still off...

Answer (score 0):

I assume the result of `getMediaDate()` is a `long` value.  When comparing the values, you are casting down to a `int`, which is truncating bits from the long and producing unexpected results.  Try something like this…

```
public int compare(GalleryBean bean1, GalleryBean bean2) {
    long value = bean2.getMediaDate() - bean1.getMediaDate();
    return value == 0 ? 0 : value > 0 ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Regardless of how big the difference is as a long value, we return an `int` of `-1`, `0` or `1`.

for descending we invert swap the beans around on the subtraction…

```
    long value = bean1.getMediaDate() - bean2.getMediaDate();
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this also but same results.  See log snippet below:

`11-24 22:15:15.022: I/ITERATOR---->(22819): gallery_bean name ---> IMG_20141117_134050.jpg gallery_bean long date ---> 1390420638000 gallery_bean date ---> 2014-01-22 15:57:18 GMT-04:00
11-24 22:15:15.023: I/ITERATOR---->(22819): gallery_bean name ---> IMG_6556.JPG gallery_bean long date ---> 1390421255000 gallery_bean date ---> 2014-01-22 16:07:35 GMT-04:00
`

Comment: i would swap bean1 and bean2 back around again. if there are no changes in output, then the sort isn't occurring or the list is being updated between you sorting it and printing it. does getGalleryImageList() return a new list or hold onto a single instance?

Comment: looks like I wrote it descending in the first place. i'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to handle the instance where one or the other is null. For instance, if NULL is less than a real value, then your check might be:

```
public int compare(GalleryBean bean1, GalleryBean bean2) {
    final int BEFORE = -1;
    final int EQUAL = 0;
    final int AFTER = 1;
    int result = EQUAL;

    if (bean1 == null){
        if (bean2 != null){
            result = BEFORE;
        }
    } else {
        if (bean2 == null){
            result = AFTER;
        } else {
            if(bean1.getMediaDate() > bean2.getMediaDate()){
                result = AFTER;
            } else if(bean1.getMediaDate() < bean2.getMediaDate()){
                result = BEFORE;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it's still not sorting properly.  Not sure why but here is sample output:

`11-24 21:59:21.278: I/ITERATOR---->(16949): gallery_bean name ---> IMG_20140601_171040.jpg gallery_bean long date ---> 1401657042000 gallery_bean date ---> 2014-06-01 17:10:42 GMT-04:00
11-24 21:59:21.279: I/ITERATOR---->(16949): gallery_bean name ---> IMG_20140601_171056.jpg gallery_bean long date ---> 1401657057000 gallery_bean date ---> 2014-06-01 17:10:57 GMT-04:00`

Comment: oh you wanted descending order. swap the > and < signs around, or swap the AFTER and BEFORE values.

Comment: I would do the latter - if you want descending order, swap the BEFORE and AFTER values.

Comment: Below answer worked so I bet this one will also.  Will try in the am.  Thanks!!